# <%= form_for@in1 do |f| %> ArgumentError in Info1#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried using :Info1 It display the form but again it gives method error
I know it's a small silly mistake but please point it out.
new.html.erb code

## add a new record

```
       <%= form_for@Info1 do |f| %>
       <p>
       <%=f.label :address %><br/>
       <%=f.text_field :address %><br/>
       </p>
       <p>
       <%=f.label :state %><br/>
       <%=f.text_field :state %><br/>
       </p>


        <p>
        <%=f.submit "Submit"%>
        </p>
        <%end%>
```

Controller Code is below
    class Info1Controller < ApplicationController
    def create
    @info1 = Info1.new(in1)
    if @info1.save
    redirect_to users_path, :notice => "student details are save "
    else
    render "new"
    end
    end

```
def new

end

def in1
params.require(:info1).permit(:address, :state)
end

end
```

Comment: space after form_for?

Comment: While pasting it was typo error sorry for that..

Comment: main error is solved by @Deepak Mahakale

Comment: Its not working @Fallenhero

Answer (score 1):

Add this in `new`

```
def new
  @info1 = Info1.new
end
```

Also change

```
<%= form_for @info1 do |f| %>
```

**NOTE**

Also, I will suggest you to use the **proper naming conventions** to avoid such errors

such that,

1. Rename the model from `Info1` to `Information` and filename to `information.rb`
2. Rename the controller from `Info1Controller` to `InformationsController` and filename to `informations_controller.rb`
3. Routes to

   ```
   resources :informations
   ```

Comment: I did it
Now it's showing me this error
NoMethodError in Info1#new
undefined method `info1s_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fa27a491a50>:0x007fa27a4903f8>
Did you mean?  info1_path
               infos_path
               info_path

Comment: Prefix Verb                 URI Pattern                        Controller#Action
info1_create GET     /info1/create(.:format)            info1#create
info1_new GET        /info1/new(.:format)               info1#new
info1_index GET     /info1(.:format)                   info1#index

Comment: change `@Info` to `@info`

Comment: Tried still not working
NameError
undefined local variable or method `info1' for

Comment: Is your Info1 even a model?

Comment: Yes Info1 is also a model

Comment: Error says `NameError undefined local variable or method 'info1'` are u using `@info1` or just `info1`